# Package requires Flutter SDK Version >=0.1.4 <2.0.0

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

I'm trying to add the path_provider package in my dependencies, but i always get this error:

```
The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown.


Because lista_tarefas depends on path_provider >=0.4.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=0.1.4 <2.0.0, version solving failed.

pub upgrade failed (1)
```

I've already tried:

- packages get
- packages upgrade
- flutter upgrade
- flutter clean
- Write other version in enviroment variable in pugspec.yaml
- Delete enviroment variable in pugspec.yaml
- Use an older version of path_provider
- Invalidating caches in Android Studio

My current pubspec.yaml file:

...

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"



dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  path_provider: "^0.4.1"

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

Path_provider doc: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider

Comment: Have you made local modifications to your flutter download or checked it out directly from git?

Comment: If you go to File->Settings->Languages&Frameworks->Flutter it should show the SDK and Flutter SDK path. Does that look ok and what version does it show ? Does it also mention Dart there as well in the version (maybe add it to the question)?

Comment: i've tried downloading the path_provider package and replacing it with the actual one, but it didn't worked so then i put it back the old(original one). 
And yes, it shows the flutter path:C:\src\flutter,
 Version :
Flutter 0.0.0-unknown • channel unknown • unknown source Framework • revision c27c4a265e (7 days ago) • 2018-11-26 17:07:24 -0500 Engine • revision eebc6a5895 Tools • Dart 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem . I solved it by ,going to the '.git' folder in your flutter SDK path and delete the config file.

Answer (score 0):

path_provider package used by you needs a flutter sdk version of lower than 2.0.0  and the sdk you are using is 2.0.0-dev.68.0 or higher. You need to either downgrade your sdk or upgrade path_provider package to a compatible one.

use the following to downgrade flutter sdk

`flutter version <version>`

Use following command to check all available versions:

```
flutter version
```

Following command tells you the current sdk version

```
flutter --version 

Flutter 1.1.8 • channel unknown • unknown source
Framework • revision 985ccb6d14 (12 months ago) • 2019-01-08 13:45:55 -0800
Engine • revision 7112b72cc2
Tools • Dart 2.1.1 (build 2.1.1-dev.0.1 ec86471ccc)
```

Answer (score 0):

one solution to this might be using the latest Path_Provder package.
`path_provider: ^1.6.24`
another one is downgrading your sdk version but I prefer the former method.

Answer (score 0):

flutter 0.0.0-unknown
Because of the git installation, things like this happen, you just have to install Flutter again

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install